# Batch Find/Replace Function for Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So the attached VBA code works for what I'm looking for but it has one significant issue.  It won't match the entire excel cell contents like I want it to.  Instead if it will replace individual text within a cell instead of a cell by cell find and replace.  Anyone have some tips how I can change to this to only replace text if the entire cell contents matches vs any text within the cell?

```
Sub MultiFindReplace()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng =  Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the argument

```
LookAt:=xlWhole
```

to the `Replace`

```
InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, _
                 replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole
```